# isSubstring(s1, s2) Complexity (language agnostic approach)

Tags: algorithm, substring

I just read in a book that conceptual:

```
isString(sring s1, string s2)
```

can be assumed as O(A+B) where A is size of s1 and B is the size of S2.

Could someone please tell where this assumption is coming from?

My logic:
If we assume A > B then there can be A-B window searches.
Assume we quit as soon as we find it.
Assume the worse case scenario where every time the last character in the sequence is false. (not sure if such sequence even exists)
So, we quit after doing B-1 comparisons for a single window.
To sum up, our total operation count should be A-B*B-1. 
Is this correct logic or perhaps I am tired and should go to sleep)))))
Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed character set, [Ukkonen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukkonen%27s_algorithm) can calculate the [Suffix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) of `s1` in time `O(A)`.  Verifying whether `s2` is a substring is a matter of verifying whether it is a valid suffix.  That traversal takes time `O(B)`.  Thereby leading to a `O(A + B)` time.

The naive algorithm is, as you describe, much slower.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is wrong because in case of failure you can know what could be the next possible window. Suppose you have : ABCDEABD and looking for ABD, then put ABD under ABC, observe that C and D doesn't match, then at this time you know that AB matched so that it is not useful to look at ABD under BCD, nor ABD under CDE, the sole next useful position to look at it is under DEA. A simple precomputation on the matched string is sufficient to compute the displacement. This is the basis of many strin-matchin algorithm. Look at Boyer-Moore or two-way string matching algorithm by Perrin and Crochemore.

Comment: FYI Boyer-Moore doesn't work very well if the character set is large.  That's because the transition tables get too big.  Therefore it is great for ASCII.  For Unicode, not so much.